# Flask web scraper problem with table head data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web scraper that gets game title information. Currently I'm scraping from the ps4 games list on Wikipedia. I'm doing this because I'm trying to learn how to incorporate scripts like a web scraper into a flask project.

I have it working pretty good but I cannot get the `<thead>` data. The columns names are listed in here and I would like these added to the csv file I generate. I thought by trying to target the `<hr>` tag I could get what I need but its not working to well. This is my latest attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

class GameScraper:
    results = []

    def fetch(self, url):
        return requests.get(url)

    def parse(self, html):
        content = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        table = content.find(id="softwarelist")
        rows = table.findAll('tr')
        header = table.find('thead')
        header_row = header.findAll('tr')
        results = header_row.findAll('th')       
        

        for row in rows:           
            if len(row.findAll('td')):
                self.results.append([data.text for data in row.findAll('td')])

    def to_csv(self):
        with open('ps4.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerows(self.results)

    def run(self):        
        ps4_list = self.fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_4_games')
        self.parse(ps4_list.text)
        self.to_csv()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = GameScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

I get this error currently:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

on this line:

```
header_row = header.findAll('tr')
```

Comment: are you trying to fetch all th? there is nothing called thead in your table.

Comment: The info you want is in the `tbody` tag not `thead`

Comment: its in <thead> I want the <th> that contains Title, Genre, Developer, Platform, Release Date. Currently my script gets the actual game info I want it just doesnt get the header information. I want the csb to have the terms I just listed in row 1 so that you know wha the game data is

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page that wikipedia returns when you send a request to them is different than the page that is displayed to a regular user. In the page that your program receives, the data that is in the head on the users end such as Title, Genre, Developer, Platform, Release Date is actually just stored in a `<th>` in the `<tbody>`.